# Every extremally disconnected collectionwise Hausdorff space is discrete.

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that every extremally disconnected collectionwise Hausdorff space is discrete?

Can someone at least give me a hint as to how to construct the proof?

Comment: According to Wikipedia (no reference given there) this holds for *first countable spaces*, not general ones?

Comment: This is false as stated: $\beta \omega$ is not discrete, but it is e.d. and cwH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is extremally disconnected (this implies the following property: if $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets then $\overline{U}$ and $\overline{V}$ are also disjoint (and open)), Hausdorff and cwH as well.

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ of all distinct points, such that $x_n \to x \in X$, where $x \notin \{x_n: n \in \omega\}$. Then as $X$ is cwH, and the set  $\{x_n: n \in \omega\}$ is discrete (this uses that $X$ is a Hausdorff space), we can find open sets $U_n$ such that $x_n \in U_n$ and such that the $U_n$ are pairwise disjoint.

But then $U = \bigcup_{n} U_{2n}$ and $V = \bigcup_{n} U_{2n+1}$ are open and disjoint and  $x \in \overline{U} \cap \overline{V} \neq \emptyset$ and this contradicts $X$ being extremally disconnected.

It follows that $X$ can only have trivial convergent sequences: ones that are eventually constant, in essence, or we could extract a sequence as above from it.

So if $X$ were **also** first countable or a sequential space (more generally), if $X$ were non-discrete, there would be a non-sequentially closed set $A$, and we'd have $x_n$, all from $A$, converging to some $x \notin A$, and we could apply the above argument to get a contradiction. But I don't think "$X$ cwH and e.d. implies $X$ discrete" holds in full generality. A counterexample is $\beta \omega$, the Čech-Stone compactification of the countable discrete $\omega$, which is even collectionwise normal.

Comment: There is however a bit of an oversight in the above: under the hypothesis on sequence $x \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ made in the second paragraph, the subset $x_{\mathbb{N}}=\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is indeed discrete but fails however to be closed (since the limit of the sequence itself doesn't belong to it). Thus, one is not in any position to apply collectionwise Hausdorff-ness, since that requires by definition *closed and discrete* subsets, if I am not mistaken. How then to remedy the reasoning presented above?